# Mysql won't start after a failed SQL import

Tags: mysql

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to import a 44gb SQL file into my local machine on Homestead (a vagrant box, virtual machine). It keeps failing! I imported a 22gb version of the same database (from an earlier date) and it imports just fine!

I have to destroy/remove the vagrant box and re-create it every time I attempt this 44gb sql import, because after it fails I can no longer start up mysql and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what's wrong.

Full error log output: **/var/log/mysql/error.log**

```
> 2020-07-02T06:25:03.951672Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit
> DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
> --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2020-07-02T06:25:03.952782Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld
> (mysqld 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) starting as process 6756 ...
> 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957298Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support
> available 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and
> rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957325Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957330Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
> 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957334Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use
> zlib 1.2.11 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957339Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux
> native AIO 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957536Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of
> pools: 1 2020-07-02T06:25:03.957612Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32
> instructions 2020-07-02T06:25:03.960176Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing
> buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
> 2020-07-02T06:25:03.972578Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization
> of buffer pool 2020-07-02T06:25:03.973957Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the
> mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can
> be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
> 2020-07-02T06:25:03.985243Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file
> format is Barracuda. 2020-07-02T06:25:03.986077Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log
> scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 81243507772
> 2020-07-02T06:25:04.323062Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned
> up to log sequence number 81248750592 2020-07-02T06:25:04.698384Z 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number
> 81253993472 2020-07-02T06:25:05.077431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing
> recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 81259236352
> 2020-07-02T06:25:05.383167Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned
> up to log sequence number 81264479232 2020-07-02T06:25:05.720469Z 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number
> 81269722112 2020-07-02T06:25:06.050976Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing
> recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 81274964992
> 2020-07-02T06:25:06.137325Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned
> up to log sequence number 81276158388 2020-07-02T06:25:06.140561Z 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
> 2020-07-02T06:25:06.140574Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
> 2020-07-02T06:25:06.160188Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which
> must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 444 row operations to undo
> 2020-07-02T06:25:06.160206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 47616
> 2020-07-02T06:25:06.160217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch
> of log records to the database... InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3
> 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
> 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
> 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74
> 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83$2020-07-02T06:25:06.770581Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Apply batch completed 2020-07-02T06:25:08.680788Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
> 2020-07-02T06:25:08.680888Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared
> tablespace for temporary tables 2020-07-02T06:25:08.681013Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the
> file full; Please wait ... 2020-07-02T06:25:08.687079Z 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted
> transactions 2020-07-02T06:25:08.687182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back
> trx with id 47167, 444 rows to undo 2020-07-02T06:25:08.746977Z 0
> [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: fsync() returned EIO, aborting. 2020-07-02
> 06:25:08 0x7fa9926de740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread
> 140366282876736 in file ut0ut.cc line 918 InnoDB: We intentionally
> generate a memory trap. InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to
> http://bugs.mysql.com. InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures
> or crashes, even InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there
> may be InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
> InnoDB:
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
> InnoDB: about forcing recovery. 06:25:08 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
> This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this
> binary or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt,
> improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by
> malfunctioning hardware. Attempting to collect some information that
> could help diagnose the problem. As this is a crash and something is
> definitely wrong, the information collection process might fail.
> 
> key_buffer_size=16777216 read_buffer_size=131072
> max_used_connections=0 max_threads=151 thread_count=0
> connection_count=0 It is possible that mysqld could use up to
> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
> 76388 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
> variables in the equation.
> 
> Thread pointer: 0x0 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following
> information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages
> after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom = 0
> thread_stack 0x30000
> /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xeaddfb]
```

If trying to connect to mysql:

```
root@homestead:/etc/mysql/conf.d# mysql -uhomestead -p****
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

The error I'm getting when trying to start up mysql:

```
root@homestead:/etc/mysql/conf.d# service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

root@homestead:/etc/mysql/conf.d# journalctl -xe
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-6, logical block 36059143
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-6, logical block 36059144
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-6, logical block 36059145
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-6): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 18 (offset 0 size 4198400 starting block 36060152)
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-6): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 18 (offset 0 size 6295552 starting block 36060664)
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-6): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 18 (offset 0 size 8388608 starting block 36061176)
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-6): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 18 (offset 8388608 size 2101248 starting block 36061688)
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-6): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 18 (offset 8388608 size 4194304 starting block 36062200)
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead mysqld[1012]: Unable to determine if daemon is running: No such file or directory
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 02 09:35:49 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

MYSQL configuration file - **/etc/mysql/conf.d contents**:

> [mysql] innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
> innodb_log_file_size = 1G innodb_write_io_threads = 16
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

*I checked the log and find this line in particular that might be an indicator of what's going on, although I have no idea what it means:
**[ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: fsync() returned EIO, aborting.***

**So my questions are:**

1. What's causing the SQL import to fail?
2. What's causing the MYSQL service to not start up?

Please note that:

1. I've tried running innodb recovery mode at different levels, the
   'service start mysql' comes out with the same response as above
   (failed to start), every time.
2. There is plenty of disk space on the virtual machine in the mysql disk drive

If you can help, please do! I've run into this problem on multiple occasions. Last time I simply gave up, but I really need a solution since I don't know how to restore my larger DB file backups since this keeps happening!

Comment: How are you doing the import?

Comment: I use HeidiSQL > File > Run SQL file

Comment: Try doing the import from the MySQL command line.
Delete the existing database, start MySQL, navigate to the directory where the backup.sql file is located, run "mysql" to get into the MySQL prompt, create the database (CREATE DATABASE foo;), use the database (USE DATABASE foo;), then run this command: SOURCE backup.sql;

Comment: Well one of the issues is that I can no longer start mysql, so removing the database isn't do-able and cannot start mysql? I'm happy to try importing through command line instead, but this doesn't really show what's going wrong?

Comment: I've deleted the vm box and will re-install and try importing from command line. I have a feeling the results will be the same though :(

Comment: It's obvious you have a problem with your storage, specifically whatever device is represented by dm-6. You'll need to work out which device that is (hint: look in the `/dev/disk/by-id` directory) and then take the appropriate action.

Comment: Ok, trying to import via command line and I keep getting this error now: ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 2019: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Update - the SQL won't import and keeps failing. I have one table that has a mediumblob field, and that table is about 5gb in size. I've attempted to increase the max allowed packet but this didn't resolve the issue it just froze up my machine and had it restart. I'll now try to re-export the database into individual tables to see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was to use the --hex-blog flag when using mysqldump to export the database. Just wanted to post this in case it helps anyone else. Blob fields can be problematic!